# Can a php class' static member be pointed?

Tags: php, class, pointers, static

```
class ab{
    public static $abc = 34;
    public static function asd(){
        $a = "abc";
        echo self::$a;  //output 34;
    }
}
ab::asd();
```

i want to find a way to point to a class static member .like the example above,how can i make this work?

Comment: What have You tried? What is the error You get? You should be able to point that method like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access a static variable, the syntax is the following:

```
MyClass::$variable
```

So what you're doing lacks the indirection:

```
echo self::$$a;  //output 34;
```

This works with regular variables the same way:

```
$variable
```

and with indirection:

```
$name = "variable";
$$name
```

An advice for your next question: Try to be more precise in your question. Pay attention to the following:

- What you have
- What it should do
- What actually does
- Where the error occurs if you know

This helps to give relevant answers more quickly instead of engaging in a meta-discussion to clarify your question.

Comment: @WouterH: You can do the same with regular variables: `$name = "my_variable"; $$name`

Comment: I would have done something with the `eval()` function, but this is way easier :)